# Error while implementing Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on an android app. I want playstore like UI, so I put that horizontal drawer and made all of my activities as fragments. Now when I open my activity, it crashes, means "Unfortunately app is stopped".

Message in log:

```
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bingo.main/com.bingo.main.Start}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at com.bingo.main.Recruitment.onCreateView(Recruitment.java:21)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5113)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
04-06 17:24:07.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1059):     ... 11 more
```

If the remove the following statement it works but without the fragments:

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();`
```

Please help me out!

Comment: Line 21 of Recruitment.java?

Comment: What is `Recruitment.java` line 21?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marco said, you have a class called Recruitment and in its onCreateView() method there is a Null PointerException - look specifically at line 21. Try debugging the program and find out what is null - possibly the fragmentManager itself or in this line:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
```

You may not have a 'fragment' instantiated yet.